# the power regression by basicTrendline packages in R

Tags: r, excel, model, non-linear-regression

I wanna perform a power regression model for my analysis in water quality.
In one of its sections I have these 2  series data:

```
 Q=  0.7409845 1.2736854 0.0713900 1.5316926 1.4607059 0.6124793 1.5902551 1.7286422
  1.6547936 1.6088377 1.6054299 1.7810355 1.4429110 1.1905836 2.2374064 1.3004641
 1.7137979 1.6578471 1.6386083 1.0181250

Cl= 1.6863990 0.9932518 1.7749524 1.1631508 2.0918641 0.9162907 1.1631508 1.3862944
  1.2809338 1.0647107 2.3978953 1.4350845 1.6677068 1.8245493 1.7578579 1.6677068
 1.4816045 1.3862944 1.2527630 1.3862944
```

I want to set power regression like this that performed in Excel :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1II6q.png)

So show the equation and the square R and the regression line in the plot in R.
I just know the basicTrendline  packages for this work
it works for the linear model but for power, No.

```
   library(basicTrendline)
Q = log(gol$debi)
Cl = log(gol$Cl)
trendline(x = Q,y = Cl, model ="power2P",show.pvalue = F
          ,ePos.x = "topleft",eDigit = 3,CI.level = 0.95,xlab = "Q",ylab = "Cl"
          ,type="p",Pvalue.corrected = F)
```

It showed this message when I ran it, while none of my data is below zero:

```
Error in trendline_summary(x = x, y = y, model = model, Pvalue.corrected = Pvalue.corrected,  : 
  
           'power2P' model need ALL x values greater than 0. Try other models.
```

Please help me with this packager other I just want to make something like excel that I send pictures of in R studio.

Answer (score 0):

The results seem a bit different than the Excel version. Wondering if those "Logs" are being done to a different base?

```
 plot(log(Cl) ~ log(Q) )
 trendline <- lm(log(Cl)~log(Q))
 abline(trendline)
 trendline
#------
Call:
lm(formula = log(Cl) ~ log(Q))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(Q)  
    0.37431     -0.02898  
#---------------
 title(main="Log(Cl)~Log(C)")
```

[image]

Your Excel "logs" are all greater than 0, so it wouldn't be the case that Excel was using log-base-10. That would make the values even more negative. So how the log of 0.7 becomes positive is a great mystery. Maybe you need to explain or offer a citation to this "power regression" method. It doesn't look like standard statistics or mathematics.

Comment: The data I wrote in this question (Q,Cl) has already been logarithmic